# Change the IP Address of EC2 Instance

Tags: ip, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

Is there any way I could change my ec2 instance ip to one that is within (preferably) the 10.x.x.x, 172.16.x.x or 192.168.x.x. I have a hunch something like this might be doable with Amazon vpc but I wouldn't know how to do so.

Comment: Changing this will not help you [circumvent Netflix access controls](https://serverfault.com/q/855871/153161).

Answer (score 0):

Once an EC2 instance is launched, it's assigned a public and private IP address at boot time. An instance's private IP address will never change during the lifetime of that instance. However, its public IP address can change under certain circumstances.

Note: Public and private DNS names are constructed based upon an instance's public and private IP addresses. So, if an instance's public IP address changes, the public DNS name will also change accordingly.